# Получить только год из строки

Tags: php

Есть строка типа **25.02.2017**

Каким образом получить только год, то есть только число **2017** ?

Числа (дата) всегда разная.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, вы можете переводить эту дату в [timestamp](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php), а затем уже из этого генерировать что угодно с помощью функции [date()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

В вашем случае это будет примерно так:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('25.02.2017');
$year = date('Y', $timestamp);
```

А уже вместо '25.02.2017' передавайте любую переменную.

Преимуществом будет то, что дату вы можете указывать в различных форматах, хоть '25 февраля 2017'. А с помощью date() вы сможете получить год, месяц, день, неделю, високосный ли год и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать **[explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)**, чтобы разбить строку с помощью разделителя.

Функция выглядит так:

```
array explode (string $delimiter, string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX])
```

В данном случае разделитель (delimiter) является точкой. Далее из получившегося массива взять последний элемент

Comment: а чем этот метод лучше например этого? `$date = '20.01.2017'; $out = substr(strrchr($date, "."), 1);`

Comment: @Денис А где-то написано, что этот метод лучше, чем другой?

Comment: @Денис ничем не лучше, используй какой знаешь.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто поинтересовался) спасибо))

Comment: @Денис методов придумать можно кучу. Использовать можно любой. Этот вариант один из...

Answer (score 0):

Выше предложили explode() и даты. Можно и регуляркой:

```
preg_match('#\d{2}.\d{2}.(\d{4})#isu','25.02.2017', $matches);
echo $matches[1]
//2017
```

Документация на функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Как уже озвучивалось выше, есть куча способов. Вот один из самых странных:

```
<?php
$d='25.02.2017';
echo $d[-4].$d[-3].$d[-2].$d[-1];
```

Но... Никогда так не делайте:)
Правильный способ получения последних четырех символов из строки:

```
<?php
$d='25.02.2017';
echo substr($d, -4);
```

Comment: "Правильный способ" вы серьёзно? Как минимум делать надо так `echo date('Y', strtotime('25.02.2017'));`

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, прочитайте мой ответ. Я писал "правильный способ получения последних четырех символов". Что касается решения конкретной задачи, то здесь нужно исходить из совокупности факторов: что мы пишем: скрипт парсинга? Автоматизация? Разбираем ответ API? Важна скорость? Масштабируемость? Валидация данных? Решаем code-golf.io задачу может быть, почему нет :)?